# Why GIT commit need 30GB of memory for a commit?

Tags: git-commit

I have a big repository, around 80GB

```
git --version
#git version 1.7.12
git init .
#Initialized empty Git repository in /reponame/.git/
git add -A .

git commmit -m "Backup 2012-08-19 03:43:44"
#fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 32220431361 bytes)
#[master (root-commit) 8053f0d] Backup 2012-08-19 03:43:44
```

Why GIT need 30GB of memory for a commit?

This is not in accordance with the first paragraph of the home main home of GIT:

> Git is a free and open source distributed version control system designed to handle everything from small to **very large projects with speed and efficiency.**

Comment: Git is designed for storing source code, but not 80 GB of source code! I'm currently using it with a repository of 120+ MB of code, and it works pretty well.

Comment: What the hell are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: GIT is not only for source code, also designers, binary files, "very large projects". http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Comment: @origamicoder To versioning a folder, "big" folder.

Comment: try ->  git config --global pack.windowMemory 256m   where you can change 256 to 128 or 512 or 1024 or more depending upon what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is in the working directory. When you did the

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Backup..."
```

You are effectively telling git to "record changes to the repository," which in freshly initialized directory of 80Gbs of things, that can be a lot of changes.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html

Comment: You are not answering the question, The question is Why GIT commit need 30GB of memory for a commit? the question is not What is a git commit?

Comment: Git has issues with large files. Even though they tend to show fragmented checkouts , it turns out they consider whole repository. try increasing window memory , and threads. it might work for you.